# C++ Linked List -- Reading in a file and sorting it based on number

Tags: c++, list, file, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am working on reading in a file. It is filled line by line with things such as the following:

```
e 2
b 1
a 3   
h 5
c 4
```

If I were to sort these by the number I would get the word "beach". I need to do this but at a larger scale.  I currently have two errors. There are lines I read in which have a space and a number [ " " 6 ] and my program will not append them/sort these into my linked list and therefore this is causing a segmentation error because my for loop for printing is meant to loop through all 53 words.

Is there any fix for as to why the spaces aren't showing up in my linked list? Also, about 44/53 of the words correctly find their places using my `addInOrder` function but yet there a few that don't, is there a reason for this?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

struct ListNode
{
    string letter;
    string num;
    ListNode *next;
};

void append(ListNode *&h, string l, string n);
void addInOrder(ListNode *&h, string l, string n);
void printList(ListNode *h, int &lengthOfFile);
void deleteNode(ListNode *&h, string l, string n);
void deleteList(ListNode *&h);

int main()
{
    string letter;
    string num;
    string lines;
    int lengthOfFile = 0;
    const string FILENAME = "file link";
    ifstream inFile(FILENAME);

    /*if (inFile)
    {
        while (getline( inFile, lines )) 
        {
            lengthOfFile++;
            cout << "Hello...1" << endl;
        }
    }*/
    ListNode *head = nullptr;

    if (inFile)
    {
        string line;
        for (int lineNum = 1; getline(inFile, line); lineNum++)
        {
            stringstream ss(line);
            string word;

            for (int wordNum = 1; ss >> word; wordNum++)
            {

                if (wordNum == 1)
                {
                    char c = word[0];

                    if (isalpha(c))
                    {
                        cout << "letter: " << c << endl;
                        letter = c;
                    }
                    else if (word == "!" or word == ".")
                    {
                        cout << "letter: " << word << endl;
                        letter = word;
                    }
                    else if (word != "!" or word != ".")
                    {
                        cout << "letter: " << "  " << endl;
                        cout << "number: " << word << endl;
                        letter = "  ";
                        num = word;
                        lengthOfFile++;
                    }
                }
                if (wordNum == 2)
                {
                    cout << "number: " << word;
                    num = word;
                    lengthOfFile++;
                }
                if (wordNum == 2)
                {
                    cout << endl;
                    append(head, letter, num);
                    //cout << "letter: " << letter << "   and   num: " << num << endl;
                    cout << endl;
                    addInOrder(head, letter, num);
                    //cout << "letter: " << letter << "   and   num: " << num << endl;
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << endl;
                }
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    inFile.close();
    }

    cout << "lengthOfFile++;: " << lengthOfFile << endl;

    printList(head, lengthOfFile);
}

void append(ListNode *&h, string l, string n)
{
    // create a new ListNode and set data and next
    ListNode *newNode;
    newNode = new ListNode;
    newNode->letter = l;
    //cout << "l: " << l << endl;
    newNode->num = n;
    //cout << "n: " << n << endl;
    newNode->next = nullptr;
}

void addInOrder(ListNode *&h, string l, string n)
{
    // create a new ListNode and set data
    ListNode *newNode;
    newNode = new ListNode;
    newNode->letter = l;
    //cout << "l: " << l << endl;
    newNode->num = n;
    //cout << "n: " << n << endl;
    newNode->next = nullptr;

    // if list is empty, assign head to new ListNode; otherwise, 
    // find where to add in (non-descending) order
    if (h == nullptr)
    {
        h = newNode;
        newNode->next = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        ListNode *prev = nullptr;
        ListNode *curr = h;

        // find location to add
        while (curr != nullptr && curr->num < n)
        {
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }

        // if prev is nullptr, then we're adding to the beginning
        // of the list; else, adding to end or between two nodes
        if (prev == nullptr)
        {
            h = newNode;                    
            newNode->next = curr;
        }
        else
        {
            prev->next = newNode;
            newNode->next = curr;
        }
    }
}

void printList(ListNode *h, int &lengthOfFile)
{
    ListNode * ptr = h; 

    // loop through and print data
    for(int i = 0; i < lengthOfFile; i++)
    {
        cout << ptr->letter << " ";
        cout << ptr->num << " ";
        cout << endl;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please get yourself familiar with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) concept and edit your question accordingly. I believe that not all of this code is required to represent the issue - especially the commented out text

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you want to mean by this?
There are lines I read in which have a space and a number [ " " 6 ] and my program will not append them/sort these into my linked list and therefore this is causing a segmentation error because my for loop for printing is meant to loop through all 53 words

Comment: I mean, ignoring the memory leak that seems to be in the code for.. absolutely no reason, there is a lot of excess code in this that isn't related to the problem. If you could format the code down to only what is required to recreate the problem would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

1)
The problem is in the following line:

```
ss >> word
```

The `operator >>` is eating up whitespace and looking for a valid (non-whitespace) character.

To get a single character from the stream [`ss.get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) should be used.

2)  If you want to compare to a character literal, use single apostrophe `'`.
But then also remeber to extract a character from `line`.